# Nextcloud theming not working in v14

Tags: nextcloud

Recently upgraded my Nextcloud install to v14. I've got a few edits made to one of the core javascript files which I've always copied into the `nextcloud/themes/mytheme/apps/someapp/js/blah.js` directory and it would get loaded and executed at runtime *instead of/in place of* the original file under `nextcloud/apps/someapp/js/blah.js`.

This doesn't seem to be working now. If I add an `alert()` to a line of code in core, the alert runs. If I copy unmodified core into `mytheme/...` and add the `alert()` there, the code never runs. Has the functionality of theming changed in v14, or am I missing something?

Comment: Dumb question: have you activated the theme after the upgrade? In owncloud themes tend to get deactivated during the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, great reminder. Yeah, added the theme to `config.php` still no change. I haven't ruled out a fat-fingered bungle on my part. The javascript errors are hard to track down sometimes with the built-in firefox debugger.  Guess I'll merge my changes from themes into core and document it for the next upgrade.